# ¿Cómo cerrar ventana principal al cerrar ventana secundaria (TopLevel)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo una aplicación que abre una ventana principal (`Tk()`) y después dejo de trabajar en esa ventana principal, la oculto y abro una nueva (`TopLevel()`), cuando presiono la <kbd>X</kbd>  que por defecto traen todas las ventanas para cerrarlas (en esa ventana secundaria), me doy cuenta que no se mata el loop de la ventana principal.

Esto lo digo porque  cuando presiono <kbd>▶</kbd> en PyCharm y hago lo dicho arriba (el supuesto cierre), al final no se me desactiva el símbolo <kbd>■</kbd>:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que me da a entender que el ciclo principal aun esta corriendo.

Este es un ejemplo del código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def validar():
    if entrada1.get()=="lili":
        abrirventana2()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("cuidado!","pass incrrecto")

def abrirventana2():
    ventana.withdraw()
    win=tk.Toplevel()
    win.geometry('380x300+500+100')
    win.configure(background='dark turquoise')
    win.title("ventana2")
    e3=tk.Label(win,text="Bienvnidos a la segunda ventana",bg="pink",fg="white")
    e3.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)
    boton2=tk.Button(win,text='Ok close',command=win.destroy)
    boton2.pack(side=tk.TOP)

def cerrarventana():
    ventana.destroy()


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("ventana 1")
ventana.geometry('400x400')
ventana.configure(background='yellow')

e1=tk.Label(ventana,text="password:", bg="blue", fg="white")
e1.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
entrada1=tk.Entry(ventana)
entrada1.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)

boton=tk.Button(ventana,text="nueva ventana",fg="red",command=abrirventana2)
boton.pack(side=tk.TOP)
boton3=tk.Button(ventana,text="Vaiidar Pass", fg="Green",command=validar)
boton3.pack(side=tk.TOP)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente el proceso continua su ejecución porque el mainloop de la app continua ejecutándose, dado que la ventana principal sigue existiendo (solo se ha ocultado). Cerrar la ventana hija solo implica eso, lógicamente no va a terminar con la aplicación completa porque se perdería el sentido propio de una ventana secundaria.

Para que al cerrar la ventana secundaria se cierre la app necesitas capturar el evento generado al pulsar el botón de cierre del gestor de ventanas y llamar al método `destroy` del padre, no de la ventana `Toplevel`. Para ello debes hacer uso del mecanismo conocido como [administradores de protocolo](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#protocols):

```
ventana.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)
```

El código quedaría así:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def validar():
    if entrada1.get() == "lili":
        abrir_ventana_secundaria()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("cuidado!", "pass incorrecto")

def cerrar_app():
    ventana.destroy()

def abrir_ventana_secundaria():
    ventana.withdraw()
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", cerrar_app)
    win.geometry('380x300+500+100')
    win.configure(background='dark turquoise')
    win.title("ventana2")
    e3 = tk.Label(win, text="Bienvenidos a la segunda ventana",bg="pink",fg="white")
    e3.pack(padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5, fill=tk.X)
    boton2=tk.Button(win, text='Ok close', command=win.destroy)
    boton2.pack(side=tk.TOP)


ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("ventana 1")
ventana.geometry('400x400')
ventana.configure(background='yellow')

e1 = tk.Label(ventana, text="password:", bg="blue", fg="white")
e1.pack(padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
entrada1=tk.Entry(ventana)
entrada1.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

boton=tk.Button(ventana, text="nueva ventana", fg="red",
                command=abrir_ventana_secundaria)
boton.pack(side=tk.TOP)
boton3=tk.Button(ventana, text="Validar Pass", fg="Green", command=validar)
boton3.pack(side=tk.TOP)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Si al pulsar `boton2` de la ventana secundaria debe también cerrase la app llama a la misma callback (`cerrar_app`).

Partiendo de la base que desconozco la estructura completa de tu aplicación real, si tu ventana principal solo va a servir para la autentificación, deberías cambiar el orden y que la mayor parte de la interacción se produzca siempre con la ventana principal, lo cual es más lógico y facilita mucho las cosas en la mayoría de los casos. Es decir, ocultar la ventana principal nada más iniciar la app, abrir una secundaria para la autentificación y que cuando esta se produzca destruir la ventana secundaria y volver a mostrar la principal.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo, hice la pregunta esperando a que tu me respondieras, pues he visto tus aportes  a la comunidad.

Infinitamente agradecido, me funciono perfectamente, lo preguntado e igualmente aplique el consejo de la ventana principal en la que mas se trabajara, porque como has dicho, tenia mi ventana principal unicamente para loguear.