# ¿Cómo vuelvo a la ventana de mi modulo principal?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy empezando la programación en Phyton y he ido aprendiendo mediante tutoriales.
Mi problema es el siguiente:
Tengo un botón en la ventana de mi modulo uno, que quiero que me lleve a mi modulo dos cerrando la misma ventana y viceversa.. lo intento hacer así y me da error. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
#Este es un archivo
from tkinter import *
from secundaria import *

class ClaseMenu():

    def fn_MenuPpal(self):
        self.menuPpal = Tk()
        self.menuPpal.title("Libertad Financiera Mofidicar")
        self.menuPpal.wm_state("zoomed")
        self.menuPpal.configure(background="honeydew")


        Label(self.menuPpal,text=("LIBERTAD FINANCIERA"),width="51",font= 
        ("Andalus",40),bg="lime green",fg="white").place(x=0,y=0)
        Label(self.menuPpal,text=("Menu"),font=("Andalus",18),bg= 
        ("honeydew")).place(x=50,y=100)
        Label(self.menuPpal,text=("Menu"),font=("Andalus",18),bg= 
        ("honeydew")).place(x=1315,y=100)
        Label(self.menuPpal,text=("Autor: Abraham Arismendi"),font= 
        ("Andalus",18),fg=("red"),bg=("honeydew")).place(x=550,y=780)
        Button(self.menuPpal,text=("Saldo en Cuentas"),width="13",font= 
        ("Comic Sans MS",12),bg=("honeydew")).place(x=10,y=150)
        Button(self.menuPpal,text=("Pagos y Servicios"),width="13",font= 
        ("Comic Sans MS",12),bg= 
        ("honeydew"),command=fn_abrirPagosyServicio).place(x=10,y=200)
        Button(self.menuPpal,text=("Password"),width="13",font=("Comic Sans 
        MS",12),bg=("honeydew")).place(x=10,y=250)
        Button(self.menuPpal,text=("Cerrar"),width="13",font=("Comic Sans 
        MS",12),bg= 
        ("honeydew"),command=self.menuPpal.destroy).place(x=10,y=750)
        self.menuPpal.mainloop()

    def fn_abrirPagosyServicio(self):
        obj_secundaria.fn_PagosyServicios()
        self.fn_cerrarVentanaMenu()

    def fn_cerrarVentanaMenu(self):
        self.menuPpal.withdraw()

#Instancias:
obj_menuPpal = ClaseMenu()
obj_secundaria = ClasePagosyServicios()


#Este es el segundo archivo(Modulo2)
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class ClasePagosyServicios():

    def fn_PagosyServicios(self):
        self.pagosyservicios = tk.Toplevel()
        self.pagosyservicios.title("Saldo de Cuentas")
        self.pagosyservicios.wm_state("zoomed")
        fondoColor = "floral white"
        fondoTitulo = "#00796B"
        fondoBoton = "white"
        letraTitulo = "Imprint MT Shadow"
        self.pagosyservicios.configure(background=fondoColor)
        Label(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Pagos de Servicio y 
        Deudas"),width=35,height=1,font= 
        (letraTitulo,50),bg=fondoTitulo,fg="white").place(x=0,y=0)

                                                #LABELS

        Label(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Deuda Total:"),bg=fondoColor,font= 
        ("arial",16),fg="red").place(x=1200,y=150)
        Label(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Tarjetas de credito: 125.000.000 
        Bs."),bg=fondoColor,font=("arial",12),fg="red").place(x=1125,y=200)
        Label(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Pagos y servicios: 125.000.000 
        Bs."),bg=fondoColor,font=("arial",12),fg="red").place(x=1125,y=230)
        Label(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Deuda: 125.000.000 
        Bs."),bg=fondoColor,font=("arial",12),fg="red").place(x=1125,y=260)
        Label(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Total: 600.000.000 
        Bs."),bg=fondoColor,font=("arial",14),fg="red").place(x=1125,y=290)

                                            #BUTTONS

        Button(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Tarjetas de 
        Creditos"),width=15,bg=fondoBoton,font= 
        ("arial",11)).place(x=50,y=120)
        Button(self.pagosyservicios,text= 
        ("Servicios"),width=15,bg=fondoBoton,font= 
        ("arial",11)).place(x=250,y=120)
        Button(self.pagosyservicios,text= 
        ("Deudas"),width=15,bg=fondoBoton,font= 
        ("arial",11)).place(x=450,y=120)
        Button(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Volver"),width="13",font=("Comic 
        Sans MS",12),bg= 
        ("white"),command=self.pagosyservicios.destroy).place(x=50,y=750)
        Button(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Menu 
        Principal"),bg=fondoBoton,font= 
        ("arial",12),command=self.fn_menuPrincipal).place(x=20,y=30)

        self.pagosyservicios.mainloop()

    def fn_menuPrincipal(self):
        #funcion para vevolvereme a la ventana principal
        print("Menu Principal")

#Instancias:
moduloDos = ClasePagosyServicios()
moduloDos.fn_PagosyServicios()
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. No debes nunca tener dos ventanas principales (`tkinter.Tk`) y por tanto dos mainloops en el mismo proceso. Debes usar `toplevel` para crear ventanas secundarias. No termino de entender que utilidad quieres darle a tu código, ¿se puede considerar una de las ventanas como ventana principal y la otra como secundaria (dialogo de ayuda, de configuración, etc)?

Comment: Allí coloqué el código original.. Por favor me podrías decir en que estoy fallando.. Ya corregí la segunda ventana por Toplevel()

Answer (score 1):

Primero, en relación a la primera versión de la pregunta principalmente (aunque en esta última edición llamas al *mainloop* también en la ventana `Toplevel`, lo cual es incorrecto también), no debes nunca tener dos ventanas principales (`tkinter.Tk`) y por tanto dos *mainloops* en el mismo proceso de forma concurrente.

Si quieres abrir ventanas secundarias debes usar `Toplevel`. El `mainloop` no es más que un ciclo infinito encargado de redibujar la app  y de procesar y responder a los eventos y tareas pendientes. Si se usan dos *mainloop* en un mismo proceso insertamos un ciclo infinito dentro de otro y puede acabar muy mal.

`Toplevel` usa el mismo *mainloop* de la ventana principal. Si queremos tener varias ventanas principales se deben crear cada una en un proceso distinto y, de ser necesario, comunicar los procesos de forma segura entre si.

En cuanto al problema principal del código actual:

- No debes instanciar la clase hija en el módulo importado:

  ```
  #Instancias:
  moduloDos = ClasePagosyServicios()
  moduloDos.fn_PagosyServicios()
  ```

  Cuando se importa un módulo en Python, todo el código a nivel de módulo (global) no incluido dentro de [`if __name__ == "__main__"`](http://En%20este%20caso,%20si%20esto%20ocurre%20se%20vuelve%20a%20mostrar%20la%20ventana%20principal.) es ejecutado en el preciso momento ene el que se importa. En tu caso, cuando haces `from secundaria import *` en tu módulo principal, se crea y se muestra la ventana secundaria en ese preciso instante.
- La instancia de la ventana hija debe hacerse en el módulo principal después de instanciar la ventana principal para poder pasarle esta última (instancia de `tkinter.Tk`).
- No llames al método `mainloop` de la ventana hija, esto como ya se comentó crea un ciclo infinito dentro de otro y en este caso conlleva que por ejemplo la ventana principal no pueda ocultarse.

No uses `from modulo import *` para importar si no está justificado, es una mala práctica en el 99% de los casos y solo está justificada en unos casos muy concretos. Hay tres razones principales, primero se puebla el espacio de nombres actual sin necesidad, segundo, derivado del anterior, es fácil provocar solapamientos de nombres entre namespaces con los consiguientes errores (muchos difíciles de depurar), por último dificulta mucho la legibilidad del código. Ahorrarse unos cuantos caracteres al codificar no es una razón para su uso y a la larga suele salir muy caro.

Tu código teniendo en cuenta todo lo anterior podría quedar así:

**principal.py**:

```
import tkinter as tk
from secundaria import ClasePagosyServicios



class ClaseMenu:

    def fn_MenuPpal(self):
        self.menuPpal = tk.Tk()
        self.menuPpal.title("Libertad Financiera Mofidicar")
        self.menuPpal.wm_attributes('-zoomed', 1)
        self.menuPpal.configure(background="honeydew")

        self.obj_secundaria = ClasePagosyServicios(self.menuPpal)

        tk.Label(self.menuPpal, text=("LIBERTAD FINANCIERA"), width="51", 
                 font=("Andalus", 40), bg="lime green", fg="white").place(x=0, y=0)
        tk.Label(self.menuPpal, text=("Menu"), font=("Andalus", 18),
                 bg=("honeydew")).place(x=50, y=100)
        tk.Label(self.menuPpal, text=("Menu"), font=("Andalus", 18),
                 bg=("honeydew")).place(x=1315, y=100)
        tk.Label(self.menuPpal, text=("Autor: Abraham Arismendi"),
                 font=("Andalus", 18), fg=("red"), bg=("honeydew")).place(x=550, y=780)
        tk.Button(self.menuPpal, text=("Saldo en Cuentas"), width="13",
                  font=("Comic Sans MS", 12), bg=("honeydew")).place(x=10, y=150)
        tk.Button(self.menuPpal, text=("Pagos y Servicios"), width="13",
                  font= ("Comic Sans MS", 12), bg= ("honeydew"),
                  command=self.fn_abrirPagosyServicio).place(x=10, y=200)
        tk.Button(self.menuPpal, text=("Password"), width="13",
                  font=("Comic Sans MS", 12), bg=("honeydew")).place(x=10, y=250)
        tk.Button(self.menuPpal, text=("Cerrar"), width="13",
                  font=("Comic Sans MS", 12), bg=("honeydew"),
                  command=self.menuPpal.destroy).place(x=10, y=750)

    def fn_abrirPagosyServicio(self):
        self.obj_secundaria.fn_PagosyServicios()
        self.fn_cerrarVentanaMenu()

    def fn_cerrarVentanaMenu(self):
        self.menuPpal.withdraw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj_menuPpal = ClaseMenu()
    obj_menuPpal.fn_MenuPpal()
```

**secundaria.py**:

```
import tkinter as tk



class ClasePagosyServicios:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.pagosyservicios = None

    def fn_PagosyServicios(self):
        self.pagosyservicios = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.pagosyservicios.title("Saldo de Cuentas")
        self.pagosyservicios.wm_attributes('-zoomed', 1)

        # Si se cierra usando el botón del gestor de ventanas se abre el menu
        self.pagosyservicios.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.fn_menuPrincipal)

        fondoColor = "floral white"
        fondoTitulo = "#00796B"
        fondoBoton = "white"
        letraTitulo = "Imprint MT Shadow"
        self.pagosyservicios.configure(background=fondoColor)
        tk.Label(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Pagos de Servicio y Deudas"),width=35,height=1,font=(letraTitulo,50),bg=fondoTitulo,fg="white").place(x=0,y=0)

        #LABELS
        tk.Label(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Deuda Total:"), bg=fondoColor, 
                 font=("arial", 16), fg="red").place(x=1200, y=150)
        tk.Label(self.pagosyservicios, text=("Tarjetas de credito: 125.000.000 Bs."),
                 bg=fondoColor, font=("arial", 12), fg="red").place(x=1125, y=200)
        tk.Label(self.pagosyservicios,text=("Pagos y servicios: 125.000.000 Bs."),
                 bg=fondoColor, font=("arial", 12), fg="red").place(x=1125, y=230)
        tk.Label(self.pagosyservicios, text=("Deuda: 125.000.000 Bs."),
                 bg=fondoColor, font=("arial", 12), fg="red").place(x=1125, y=260)
        tk.Label(self.pagosyservicios, text=("Total: 600.000.000 Bs."),
                 bg=fondoColor, font=("arial", 14), fg="red").place(x=1125, y=290)

        #BUTTONS
        tk.Button(self.pagosyservicios, text=("Tarjetas de Creditos"),width=15,
                  bg=fondoBoton, font=("arial", 11)).place(x=50, y=120)
        tk.Button(self.pagosyservicios, text= ("Servicios"), width=15,
                  bg=fondoBoton, font=("arial", 11)).place(x=250, y=120)
        tk.Button(self.pagosyservicios, text=("Deudas"), width=15,
                  bg=fondoBoton, font=("arial", 11)).place(x=450, y=120)
        tk.Button(self.pagosyservicios, text=("Volver"), width="13",
                  font=("Comic Sans MS", 12),bg=("white"),
                  command=self.pagosyservicios.destroy).place(x=50,y=750)
        tk.Button(self.pagosyservicios, text=("Menu Principal"), bg=fondoBoton,
                  font=("arial",12), command=self.fn_menuPrincipal).place(x=20, y=30)


    def fn_menuPrincipal(self):
        self.parent.deiconify()
        self.pagosyservicios.destroy()
```

No obstante creo que todo te sería mas simple si hicieras uso de la herencia a la hora de crear tus ventanas en vez de usar composición, que en este caso creo que complica las cosas sin necesidad:

**principal.py**:

```
import tkinter as tk
from secundaria import PagosyServicios



class Menu(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Libertad Financiera Modificar")
        self.wm_attributes('-zoomed', 1)
        self.configure(background="honeydew")

        self._pagos_y_servicios = None

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        tk.Label(self.frame, text=("LIBERTAD FINANCIERA"), width="51",
                 font= ("Andalus", 40), bg="lime green", fg="white").place(x=0,y=0)
        tk.Label(self.frame, text=("Menu"), font=("Andalus", 18),
                 bg= ("honeydew")).place(x=50,y=100)
        tk.Label(self.frame, text=("Menu"), font=("Andalus", 18),
                 bg= ("honeydew")).place(x=1315,y=100)
        tk.Label(self.frame, text=("Autor: Abraham Arismendi"), font= ("Andalus", 18),
                 fg=("red"), bg=("honeydew")).place(x=550, y=780)
        tk.Button(self.frame, text=("Saldo en Cuentas"), width="13",
                  font=("Comic Sans MS", 12), bg=("honeydew")).place(x=10, y=150)
        tk.Button(self.frame, text=("Pagos y Servicios"), width="13",
                  font=("Comic Sans MS",12), bg= ("honeydew"), 
                  command=self.abrir_pagos_y_servicios).place(x=10, y=200)
        tk.Button(self.frame, text=("Password"), width="13", font=("Comic Sans MS",12),
                  bg=("honeydew")).place(x=10, y=250)
        tk.Button(self.frame, text=("Cerrar"), width="13", font=("Comic Sans MS", 12),
                  bg= ("honeydew"),command=self.destroy).place(x=10, y=750)        

    def abrir_pagos_y_servicios(self):
        if self._pagos_y_servicios is None:
            self._pagos_y_servicios = PagosyServicios(self)
        else:
            self._pagos_y_servicios.deiconify()
        self.ocultar_menu()

    def ocultar_menu(self):
        self.withdraw()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_win = Menu()
    main_win.mainloop()
```

**secundaria.py**:

```
import tkinter as tk



class PagosyServicios(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title("Saldo de Cuentas")
        self.wm_attributes('-zoomed', 1)
        # Si se cierra usando el botón del gestor de ventanas se abre el menu
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.volver_menu_principal)


        fondoColor = "floral white"
        fondoTitulo = "#00796B"
        fondoBoton = "white"
        letraTitulo = "Imprint MT Shadow"

        self.configure(background=fondoColor)
        tk.Label(self, text=("Pagos de Servicio y Deudas"), width=35, height=1,
                 font=(letraTitulo, 50), bg=fondoTitulo, fg="white").place(x=0, y=0)

        #LABELS
        tk.Label(self, text=("Deuda Total:"), bg=fondoColor,
                 font= ("arial", 16), fg="red").place(x=1200, y=150)

        tk.Label(self, text=("Tarjetas de credito: 125.000.000 Bs."), 
                 bg=fondoColor, font=("arial", 12), fg="red").place(x=1125, y=200)

        tk.Label(self, text=("Pagos y servicios: 125.000.000 Bs."),
                 bg=fondoColor, font=("arial", 12), fg="red").place(x=1125, y=230)

        tk.Label(self, text=("Deuda: 125.000.000 Bs."), bg=fondoColor,
                 font=("arial", 12), fg="red").place(x=1125, y=260)

        tk.Label(self, text=("Total: 600.000.000 Bs."), bg=fondoColor,
                 font=("arial", 14), fg="red").place(x=1125, y=290)

        #BUTTONS
        tk.Button(self,text=("Tarjetas de Creditos"), width=15, bg=fondoBoton, 
                  font=("arial", 11)).place(x=50, y=120)

        tk.Button(self,text=("Servicios"), width=15, bg=fondoBoton,
                  font=("arial", 11)).place(x=250, y=120)

        tk.Button(self, text=("Deudas"), width=15, bg=fondoBoton,
                  font= ("arial", 11)).place(x=450, y=120)

        tk.Button(self, text=("Volver"), width="13", font=("Comic Sans MS", 12),
                  bg=("white"), command=self.destroy).place(x=50, y=750)

        tk.Button(self, text=("Menu Principal"), bg=fondoBoton, font=("arial", 12),
                  command=self.volver_menu_principal).place(x=20, y=30)


    def volver_menu_principal(self):
        self.parent.deiconify()
        self.withdraw()
```

Observa que debes manejar el caso en el que el usuario cierre la ventana secundaria estando oculta la principal usando un método que no sea pulsar el botón que creas en ella, por ejemplo usando el botón <kbd>X</kbd> del gestor de ventanas. Si no tienes esto en cuenta, tu aplicación no se cerrará, puedes mirarte esta pregunta relacionada para más información:

[¿Cómo cerrar ventana principal al cerrar ventana secundaria (TopLevel)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/196293/15089)

Para estos ejemplos, si lo anterior ocurre, se vuelve a mostrar la ventana principal (menú).

Comment: Ok. Tengo muchos errores, hay cosas que no entiendo mucho.. De verdad muchas gracias.. nunca pensé que me iban responder de tal manera tan explicita, me gusto mucho su explicación.. de verdad muchas gracias.. Ahora tengo mucho trabajo que hacer y estudiar cada linea que no entienda y ver porque se coloca..